# How to fix Swift Build error: no such module "ModuleName", when the package is included in dependencies?

Tags: swift, xcode12, swift-package-manager

I added this [CodeScanner](https://github/twostraws/CodeScanner/) Package from github with the package manager, however when building the compiler still gave the error:

> No such module 'CodeScanner'

I reinstalled the package, tried clean build, closing and reopening xcode, but neither of these actions worked. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your build sceme and at the `run` tab -> `info` tab switch your Build configuration to `Development`. This worked for me! I've been looking for this a few days until i found [this last comment](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/119327?page=2) in the apple dev forum